# What is the syntax for AND OR NOT in Postgres trigram search?

Tags: postgresql, pattern-matching, full-text-search, trigram, pg-trgm

I have implemented Postgres 9.6 trigram search https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/pgtrgm.html into my application which works fine for a single search term.

I can't see how to allow my users to do AND OR NOT searches though.

Currently, if I put "perl" into the search field, it will return hundreds of results.  That's great and works fine.

Now if I want to search for documents containing "perl" and also containing "javascript", no matter what search term I put in, no results come back.

I have tried for example:

```
"perl javascript"
"perl AND javascript"
"perl && javascript"
```

So I am trying to work out how I can provide to my end users a more sophisticated search than single term only.  I would like my application users to be able to do full text searches with and/or/not.

Is it possible?  If yes, what is the syntax?

Comment: `AND OR NOT searches` does not describe your problem. Please be more specific.

Comment: Hi Erwin I have updated the question with more specific use cases - is that more clear?  thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  document ~ 'perl'
AND    document ~ 'javascript';
```

This query finds ...

> documents containing "perl" and also containing "javascript"

Note that "perlane" or "javascripting" or "Kaperl" also qualify. To search for whole words, you might be interested in **text search** instead. Overview:

- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)